# Merge git repositories without common history, but with common files

Tags: git, git-merge

I have to merge two separate git repositories ORIG and WORK. WORK was created as a derivative of a subdirectory of ORIG, with some experimental changes that haven't been commited to ORIG.

```
~> mkdir WORK
~> cp -a ORIG/src/* WORK
~> cd WORK
~/WORK> # apply some experimental changes to WORK
~/WORK> git init
~/WORK> git add .
~/WORK> git commit -m "Entirely disconnected commit."
```

As a result, WORK doesn't know that it originated from ORIG, and lacks the `src` prefix of the file names.

Is it somehow possible to

- identify the commit in ORIG from which WORK was created and
- change WORK such that the full file paths 
  (i.e. `./src/FILE` instead of `./FILE`) are present,
- merge the repositories back together without losing history?

Currently I've solved the problem by

- `git mv`'ing each file in WORK to a newly created `./src` directory,
- adding ORIG as a remote,
- merging `ORIG/master` into WORK's `master`

  ```
  git merge -X theirs --allow-unrelated-histories ORIG/master
  ```

  with the `theirs` merge strategy, and reapplying 
  changes by hand, using `git diff` to find the relevant parts,

but the result is an unclean history at best:

- The history doesn't represent the common ancestry of WORK and ORIG commits.
- In the history of WORK, the files appear in the root directory 
  instead of in `./src` and files from outside `./src` don't exist in the
  history of WORK at all.

How would I produce a clean, merged history?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to

*Somehow* is pretty wide open, so yes.

> - identify the commit in ORIG from which WORK was created

The easy way is: remember it.  An alternative is to find a commit where the source tree of that commit matches the sub-tree you've saved.  This is difficult (but not impossible, and fairly fast if you're willing to do exact sub-tree matches: use the hash IDs of the sub-trees), but opens the possibility of multiple matches: Depending on the source repository, it seems quite likely that *many* commits in `ORIG` have a sub-tree that matches the root commit's tree in `WORK`.  In this case, it's possible, but not guaranteed, that any of them will be suitable.

The thing is, it does not really buy you anything—well, not yet.  It might make the merge step easier (see below).

> - change WORK such that the full file paths (i.e. `./src/FILE` instead of `./FILE`) are present

Yes, sort of; or no, depending on what you mean.  You can use `git filter-branch` to make a *copy* of the repository, and make this change in the copy.  The copy is no longer compatible with the original, but if you plan to have a flag day and switch everyone to the copy, then it's pretty straightforward.

> - merge the repositories back together without losing history?

This is the really sticky part.

Git never really *loses* history: history, in Git, *is* (are?) the commits.  Commits are permanent and unchanging.  However, Git *remembers* commits via branch names (and other names such as tags), so if you force the branch names to stop remembering some commits—this, for instance, is what `git filter-branch` does after *copying* all the filtered commits to new commits—then those commits are *effectively* forgotten.  Eventually, if you remove all ability to find those commits, Git will delete them for real, through *garbage collection*: `git gc`.

Again, that's how `git filter-branch` does its job: you tell it to copy *every* commit to a new commit, with the new commit being a lot like the original except that every `FILE` has been renamed to `src/FILE`.  Then you make all the branch names point to the last of the new copies, instead of the last of the originals.  You remove any saved original names (`git filter-branch` copies the original references just in case), remove all the other backup seat-belts and safety lines (`git reflog expire` etc), and force a garbage-collection pass, and *poof*, your original set of commits is gone, and you have only the replacement commits.

But: *Commits are snapshots.*  You have all the snapshots in `ORIG`, to which you can add all the snapshots you like from `WORK` (or the modified replacement copy made via `git filter-branch`).  The result is just a sum of commits.  It's not a history in which the two sets of work are interwoven: it's just a history that says, in effect, "on <date> these were merged together, and before then we have these two separate histories".  For instance, `ORIG` might look like this:

```
root--o--(history graph)---o   <-- master
       \                  /
        o--(branchy)--o--o   <-- feature
```

and your filtered `WORK` might look like this:

```
            o--o
           /    \
root2--o--o------o   <-- master
```

Put both into a single repository, changing the name of `WORK`'s `master` to something else, and you have:

```
            o--o
           /    \
root2--o--o------o   <-- workmaster

root--o--(history graph)---o   <-- master
       \                  /
        o--(branchy)--o--o   <-- feature
```

You can now run `git checkout master; git merge workmaster`, solve all the merge conflicts—Git will complain that every file in `src/*` that is in both `master` tip commits has an add/add conflict, since the common starting point is "no files"—and make a commit from the merged result:

```
                       o--o
                      /    \
root2--o-------------o------o   <-- workmaster
                             \
root--o--(history graph)---o--o   <-- master
       \                  /
        o--(branchy)--o--o   <-- feature
```

and you now have an `ORIG`-based repository with one new commit that joins up the two histories.

If that's sufficient for your purposes, you are now done.  If not, the rest may not really help, but I'll outline it anyway.

#### Making the merge easier and/or fussing with the history

A straightforward `git merge` is difficult because all the files conflict.  However, if you've found a point where the files all *match*, you can, instead of merging as above, use `git replace` to make a temporary graft.  You can then merge more easily and perhaps even make the replacement permanent (with another `filter-branch`, with all that this implies).

We start with the same kind of drawing as above, but pick a point where "root2" matches some commit `X` in the main repository.  Note that I've labeled the child of `root2` here as well:

```
            o--o
           /    \
root2--Y--o------o   <-- workmaster

root--o--...--X----...-----o   <-- master
       \                  /
        o--(branchy)--o--o   <-- feature
```

We now use `git replace` to tell Git: *don't look at commit `Y`, look instead at new replacement commit `Y'`* so that most of Git sees this:

```
                       o--o
                      /    \
                Y'---o------o   <-- workmaster
               /
root--o--...--X----...-----o   <-- master
       \                  /
        o--(branchy)--o--o   <-- feature
```

Commits `Y` and `root2` are still in there, it's just that Git doesn't *look* at them any more (except for things like `git gc`, or any command you run with the `--no-replace-objects` option).

To do this replacement, we find the child commit `Y` after `root2`—with luck there's just one, but if there are several we can `git replace` all of them—and run:

```
git replace --graft <hash-of-Y> <hash-of-X>
```

which makes the substitute commit `Y'`.  That gives us the drawing we made above, and now `git merge` will treat `X` as the common commit for merging the two branch tips.

Our merge will be easier (maybe) and we get:

```
                       o--o
                      /    \
                Y'---o------o   <-- workmaster
               /             \
root--o--...--X----...-----o--o   <-- master
       \                  /
        o--(branchy)--o--o   <-- feature
```

as our result.

If we run a no-filter `git filter-branch`—and we make sure we *don't* use `git --no-replace-objects filter-branch`—the filter-branch will copy the repository *without* the original `Y` and `root2` commits, using `X` and `Y'` instead.  These grafts, in other words, are now permanent in our new and yet-again-rewritten repository (another flag day changeover, though with luck or good planning, the *same* day so that there is only one flag day).